# ReturnType of Pandas UDF varies per input. How to deal? - Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I've written a pandas UDF that returns the value of a column where another column has its max value

```
@F.pandas_udf("string")
def belonging_to_max_udf(value_of: pd.Series, where_this_is_max: pd.Series) -> str :
  mx = where_this_is_max.max()
  if not pd.isnull(mx):
    return_value = value_of[where_this_is_max == mx]
    return return_value.iloc[0]
  return None
```

However, the column  'value_of'  can be of any type. In this specific example it was a string column. However, I also want to used this function for other column-types, without having to write a seperate function for all of the possible return types, i.e. I would not like to do the following:

```
@F.pandas_udf("string")
def belonging_to_max__STRING_udf(value_of: pd.Series, where_this_is_max: pd.Series) -> str :
  mx = where_this_is_max.max()
  if not pd.isnull(mx):
    return_value = value_of[where_this_is_max == mx]
    return return_value.iloc[0]
  return None


@F.pandas_udf("double")
def belonging_to_max_DOUBLE_udf(value_of: pd.Series, where_this_is_max: pd.Series) -> float:
  mx = where_this_is_max.max()
  if not pd.isnull(mx):
    return_value = value_of[where_this_is_max == mx]
    return return_value.iloc[0]
  return None

... etc for other types
```

Is there a good way to deal with this?

I tried Overloading:

```
@F.pandas_udf("string")
@F.pandas_udf("double")
def belonging_to_max_udf(value_of: pd.Series, where_this_is_max: pd.Series) -> Any:
  mx = where_this_is_max.max()
  if not pd.isnull(mx):
    return_value = value_of[where_this_is_max == mx]
    return return_value.iloc[0]
  return None
```

But doesnt work.

Comment: Not sure if I understand. What you are defining with `string`, `double` is the return type of a UDF, it has nothing to do with the type of your input i.e. `value_of` column. See [pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html) for more information.

Do you want to dynamically set the return value of a UDF, based on input column?

Comment: Hi Vlad Siv, thanks for your response. I understand that string, double concerns the return type of the UDF. The UDF however, returns a value of the value_of column (more specifically the value of this column that corresponds to the index of where where_this_is_max takes its max value). The value_of column can be a string-column (in which the returntype of the UDF is string) or a double column (in which the returntype of the UDF is double), or any other type (boolean, int etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the declarative way of defining `pandas UDF` dynamically based on the column datatype. Note that the wrapper creates `UDF` for different types, however it's transparent to the user.

```py
import pandas as pd
from typing import Any
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [("1", 1.0), ("1", 2.0), ("2", 3.0), ("2", 5.0), ("200", 10.0)],
    ("id", "v"))

# You expose only this function to users
def max_udf_wrapper(df: DataFrame, col: str):
    data_type= df.schema[col].dataType
    #dynamically construct UDF here based on col_type
    def _find_max(v: pd.Series) -> Any:
        return v.max()
    find_max_udf = pandas_udf(_find_max, data_type)
    return find_max_udf(df[col])


df.select(max_udf_wrapper(df, 'id'), max_udf_wrapper(df, 'v')).printSchema()
#root
# |-- find_max(id): string (nullable = true)
# |-- find_max(v): double (nullable = true)

df.select(max_udf_wrapper(df, 'id'), max_udf_wrapper(df, 'v')).show()

#+------------+-----------+
#|find_max(id)|find_max(v)|
#+------------+-----------+
#|         200|       10.0|
#+------------+-----------+
```

Comment: Hi Nithish. Thanks for thinking with me. However, in this case I still have to define two udfs,, max_udf_double and max_udf_string. I would like to have only one UDF

Comment: I understand so your concern is not code duplication then, would you be okay with a solution that involves casting results from the `UDF`?

Comment: I want the user of the function to not have to think about the input type (so, he also should not have to think if he has to use max_udf_double or max_udf_string, just max_udf). I am not sure how casting would fit in this picture (although the user would not have to think about which fucntion should be used, he/she should know to which format it should be casted). But if you know a good way to do that, that would very much be appreciated!  I was thinking about a writing a wrapper that dynamically creates a pandas UDF but not sure how to do that haha.

Comment: @Rens I have edited the answers, such that you can expose to the user a single function for all data types.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple utility function to deal dynamic return type

in my case, the return type is variable by the input and logic on the pandas_udf function.

### Usage

```
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir(checkpoint_dir)

def sample_pandas_udf_func(a: pd.Series, b: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # process and return dataframe
    df = pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
    df['c'] = 1
    df['d'] = 1
    return df

df = process_dynamic_pandas_udf_return(df, sample_pandas_udf_func, cols=["a", "b"])

df.printSchema()
# contains a, b, c, d columns
```

### the logic of the utility code

1. convert the dataframe, and it's schema as json and return as Map<string, string> type
2. find the schema by merging schema json.
3. convert the dataframe value json to the columns by the schema
4. rectify datetime type which is not supported on json.
5. it uses checkpoint for reducing complexity of plan and also for cacheing the middle data

I have an article here with a more detailed explanation and the code: [Exploring Dynamic Return Types in PySpark's pandas_udf](https://dss99911.github.io/ai/2024/01/24/exploring-dynamic-return-types-in-pyspark-pandas_udf.html)

Answer (score 0):

u can try this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
import pandas as pd

def belonging_to_max_udf(value_of: pd.Series, where_this_is_max: pd.Series):
    mx = where_this_is_max.max()
    if not pd.isnull(mx):
        return_value = value_of[where_this_is_max == mx]
        return return_value.iloc[0]
    return None

def dynamic_udf_wrapper(df, value_of_col_name, where_this_is_max_col_name):
    dtype = df.schema[value_of_col_name].dataType

    pandas_dtype = str(dtype.simpleString())

    udf = pandas_udf(belonging_to_max_udf, returnType=pandas_dtype)

    return df.withColumn("result", udf(df[value_of_col_name], df[where_this_is_max_col_name]))

df = [your dataframe]
result_df = dynamic_udf_wrapper(df, "your_value_of_column", "your_where_this_is_max_column")
```